# Getting ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: sqlplus, oracle12c

Yesterday I installed Oracle 12c Enterprise edition on my laptop. When I tried to connect to DB via SQLPLUS i got the below error

```
C:\Users\USER>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sun Feb 28 14:12:46 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: userdb
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I tried all the tricks mentioned on internet but couldn't get rid of this error.

I also tried below

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
ORA-01109: database not open


Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1543503872 bytes
Fixed Size                  3045984 bytes
Variable Size             989857184 bytes
Database Buffers          536870912 bytes
Redo Buffers               13729792 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 10 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 10:
'C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF'
```

also tried below but still getting error's

```
SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup nomount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1543503872 bytes
Fixed Size                  3045984 bytes
Variable Size             989857184 bytes
Database Buffers          536870912 bytes
Redo Buffers               13729792 bytes
SQL> alter database mount;

Database altered.

SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 10 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 10:
'C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF'


SQL> recover database;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01110: data file 10:
'C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF'
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 10 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 10:
'C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF'
```

Can someone help here? thanks!

Comment: alter database datafile 10 offline;

alter database open;   This will allow you to start up your instance, however all data in this file will not be present. You will need to recover this somehow. Perhaps it got deleted, or corrupted.

Comment: Well, let me try reinstalling the software again to see if the problem goes away. i am not sure on how to recover the files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've had the same problem and just want to share my solution with you, if anybody else gets the *ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress* 
Error in Oracle 12c Database. My database showed me the error everytime i tried to connect to a user of a sample schema (for ex. hr).

The following worked for me:

```
SQLPlus> connect sys as sysdba
SQLPlus> alter pluggable database all open;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this issue is :
drop the database datafile which you are getting in error , for your case "data file 10" .

SQL> alter database datafile 16 OFFLINE DROP;
Database altered.

SQL> alter database open;
Database altered.

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and i solve it.
 In fact the problem that you got is due to a changement in the destination of one or few datafiles.
In your case is the datafile 10.In fact the error is:

```
SQL> recover database;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01110: data file 10:
**strong text**'C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF'**strong text**
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 10 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 10:
'C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF'
```

The solution is to search this datafile in your hard drive an make it in the same directory used by oracle which is in your case : `C:\ORACLEDB12C\APP\USERNAME\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF`

Mention that you should do this for all datafile that you have changed its directories.I wish this will be helpful.