# Error Message when Reading a Oracle Database from Python

Tags: python, oracle

I am working in reading Oracle Database by using Python language, but the problem is that I have the following message:

```
OperationalError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-efea593191c7> in <module>
----> 1 db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'myUserName', password='myPassword', dsn=dsn_tns) 

OperationalError: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: is your database service is running? did you checked it

Comment: Yes, it is running.

By using PL/SQL, I have no problem. But when using Python, I have that message.

Comment: Did you take a look at this? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687324/getting-ora-01033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress)

Answer (score 0):

Check the open_mode after loging in as sysdba

`select open_mode from v$database;`

if the open_mode is anything other than "open", then :

```
SQL> shutdown abort;  
SQL> startup nomount;  
SQL> alter database mount;
```

Or, may be, you are trying to access a physical standby database. In that case you should try changing the connection pointing to the primary